# Windows-8 browse url,local storage

Tags: windows-8, windows-phone

I have searched around a lot but have not found much of anything in regards to local storage for Windows 8, Windows RT, and Windows Phone apps.

I want to display the browser on a page surf and search webpages. When I find the specified webpage, I want to store the url on a local storage of the device.

On another page, I want to display the URLs in a list for fast select and direct surf to the url. I am developing with visual studio 2012 and vb.net.

Answer (score 1):

Local storage options for Windows Store apps is pretty well covered in the dev center topic [Accessing app data with the Windows Runtime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464917.aspx)

In Windows 8 (Windows Store apps), you could use [app settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464917.aspx#app_settings) (registry based), [local application data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464917.aspx#local_application_data) (file-based and sandboxed) as well as the [roaming versions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464917.aspx#roaming_app_data) thereof.

Since you mentioned Windows Phone 8, I'll add that while the same Windows Storage APIs are surfaced for Windows Phone, only local application data will work directly.  In Windows Phone 8, local application data is another way of handling isolated storage; however, there is no built-in roaming data option. Additionally, app settings as implemented in Windows 8 is not available in Windows Phone, but you can use [isolated storage settings](http://www.jeffblankenburg.com/2010/10/15/31-days-of-windows-phone-day-15-isolated-storage/) which is semantically equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

I have gone through the web browser terms and conditions, and there it is clearly mentioned that you cannot use the web browser for general browsing, and if you are doing the same, your app would be rejected by the microsoft app store
For reference please go through
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2012/10/18/nine-things-you-need-to-know-about-webview.aspx#AN6